# saving setText after closing JDialog

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, jdialog, saving-data

I'm having a JDialog that works as a "Settings Window". I Choose a Save-File-Path and I click a button named Save. It Stores the Path and displays it on a `JTextField`. My problem is when i close the JDialog called "Settings" and open it again the `JTextField` doesn't display the newest Path.
I think it has something to do with the JDialog and that it doesn't store the `setText` variable. How can I store the new text in the `JTextField`?

This is a fragment of my code:

```
public class Settings extends JDialog {

textField = new JTextField("C\\:");
        textField.setBounds(10, 36, 254, 28);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setColumns(10);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              choose= new JFileChooser();
              choose.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
              choose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

              int rVal = choose.showSaveDialog(Settings.this);
              if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filename.setText(choose.getSelectedFile().getName());
                dir.setText(choose.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
                File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
               string myline = file.getAbsolutePath();

              }});

sbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             textField.setText(myline);

         }
         });
```

So I wan't to set textfield to `myline` and even after closing the JDialog, store it and display it next time you open JDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend for the `Settings` class to store the value of the settings then make sure you are using one instance of Settings and not creating a new Settings object when opening the dialog.

Comment: THANK YOU! it was that easy, i created new instances all the time. When I did a Static one, the hole thing came together! :)

Answer (score 1):

declare the myline object outside of the listener like this way

```
private string myline = "":
public class Settings extends JDialog {
textField = new JTextField("C\\:");
        textField.setBounds(10, 36, 254, 28);
        panel.add(textField);
        textField.setEditable(false);
        textField.setColumns(10);

button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              choose= new JFileChooser();
              choose.setCurrentDirectory(new java.io.File("."));
              choose.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);

              int rVal = choose.showSaveDialog(Settings.this);
              if (rVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                filename.setText(choose.getSelectedFile().getName());
                dir.setText(choose.getCurrentDirectory().toString());
                File file = choose.getSelectedFile();
                myline = file.getAbsolutePath();

              }});

sbutton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
             textField.setText(myline);

         }
         });
```

Comment: That, and use the value of the JTextField in the call to `setCurrentDirectory` to make sure the dialog is primed to whatever was previously filled in.

Comment: Tried it, but the JDialog is a class, and when i close the JDialog it feels like it removes all data and that it forgets that i `setText("some thing")`

Answer (score 0):

You can make the JFileChooser instance variable of your main class so that it remembers the last directory location. You can also initialize your text field based on current file in the chooser.